# Transfer MFVideoFormat from RGB24 to any other supported format by encoder

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I need to use the [encoder H264](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797816(v=vs.85).aspx) but the problem is that encoder does not accept except a list of MFVideoFormat.

> MFVideoFormat_I420
>
> MFVideoFormat_IYUV
>
> MFVideoFormat_NV12
>
> MFVideoFormat_YUY2
>
> MFVideoFormat_YV12

The problem is that the samples from my camera are RGB24 what shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least) two options:

1. Transform (by yourself) your RGB24 samples (bitmaps) into NV12 (or other) samples before you pass them to the encoder. It is not that hard. There are examples: https://www.google.bg/search?q=RGB+to+NV12
2. You can create an instance of Color Converter DSP (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and configure it's input to receive RGB24 samples and it's output to desired color space. Then you call ProcessInput() and ProcessOutput() to transform.